# Mutually recursive AMD modules

Tags: javascript, js-amd

I am trying to write a reasonably chunky client side web app using Javascript and jQuery. In order to organise my code, I read up on Javascript module systems and decided to go with AMD modules. Currently I'm using curl.js as my module loader, but I'm not particularly wedded to that.

Unfortunately I've now run up against an issue where two of my modules need to be mutually dependent. I was expecting it to Just Work --- but what actually happens is that loading the app just seems to stall half-way through and everything stops, with no error messages.

A quick Google shows practically no mention whatsoever of AMD and mutually recursive modules. Can I actually do this, and if so, how? (Do I need to change to a different module loader?)

If not, any suggestions on an alternative module system which does support mutually recursive modules?

Comment: If they only can go with themselves, can't you put them in the same file?

Comment: Well, yes, but the whole point of using modules is to *avoid* doing that...

Comment: Yes, but only if your code is modular… If those things depend on each other, how should your module loader know which module to define (execute) first? What would you expect?

Comment: What I would expect is module A to be given an unpopulated object referring to module B which it can then use to define methods. This then gets filled in later when module B is loaded. Obviously I can't actually *use* any of these methods until both A and B load, but I should at least be able to *define* methods. This is the way every other module system works for JS-like languages...

Comment: OK, i didn't know there are module loaders that pass the definition functions the module on which to define the methods, I've only module definition functions as constructors

Answer (score 1):

So after realising that an alternative name for 'mutual recursion' is 'circular dependencies', I found some references online (notably the [require.js manual page](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular) on the topic).

The short summary is: no, this doesn't work. There are various ways to get round it, but it fundamentally does not Just Work.

The simplest workaround is to break the dependency chain using an explicit synchronous `require()` call:

```
define(
    ["require", "NotLoadedYet"],
    function (require, NLY)
    {
        // NLY is undefined here
        return {
            doSomething: function()
            {
                var realNLY = require("NotLoadedYet"); // fetch the real NLY on demand
                realNLY.doSomething(); // actuall call the method
            }
         };
    }
);
```

Obviously this only works if you can guarantee that NotLoadedYet really has been loaded by the time you call the method.

The idea of using dynamic late-binding in a language which *already* does dynamic late-binding is pretty ew, but it does work. Sigh. There seems to be a slightly less ew technique which involves changing to use requirejs's CommonJS support instead, but I don't know how that works so I'm sticking to this.

What I'll actually do is implement a NotLoadedYetImpl module which contains the implementation and a NotLoadedYet module which proxies through the above mechanism. It's a shame Javascript doesn't do getters and setters on all properties for an object, or I could do it all automatically, too...

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer -- had a similar problem that was driving me crazy.